# String literal not being appended to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to make functions that return me an HTML element as a string so I can eventually append them to the DOM and pass them around my functions. I have paragraph, heading, and div's working but cannot for the life of me seem to get links to work.

This is the non-working [codepen](http://codepen.io/cirsca/pen/WwzNJZ?editors=0011)

The javascript in question is:

```
function link(href,text,css){
    let target = `<a href="#"></a>`;
    if(css == null ){
        return target;
    }

    return addStyles(target,css);
}
```

My addStyles function is:

```
function addStyles(target,css){
    if(css == null ){
        return target;
    }
    let props = Object.keys(css);
    props.forEach((prop)=>{
        switch(prop){
            case 'id':
                $(target).attr('id', css[prop]);
                break;
            case 'class':
                let classes = css[prop];
                if(Array.isArray(css[prop])){
                    classes = css[prop].toString().replace(',', ' ');
                } 
                $(target).addClass(classes);
                break;
            default:
                $(target).attr('data-name', 'Timi');
        }
    });
    return target;
}
```

which for a long time gave me errors but only when calling it from the `link` function. I tried hard-coding in the href to see if maybe my string literals were giving me the errors but still no avail.

while calling it from this function it works perfectly

```
function createDiv(css){
    let newDiv = $(div);
    return addStyles(newDiv,css);
}
```

I say that the addStyles function works and that I think it's the `link()` that is giving me problems because createDiv works and appends the DOM with these calls

```
app.append(createDiv({id: 'testing'}));
app.append(createDiv({class: ['bar', 'snuff']}));
app.append(createDiv()).append(createDiv({class: 'timi'})).append(paragraph('Hey guys!'));
$('#testing').append(heading(1,'Hello'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `let target = <a href="#"></a>;` is a string. you should use a DOM and manipulate its attribute instead

```
function link(href,text,css){
    let target = document.createElement('a');
    let linkText = document.createTextNode(text);

    target.appendChild(linkText);
    target.href = href;

    if(css == null ){
        return target;
    }

    return addStyles(target,css);
}
```

Comment: I think going back to vanilla JS and using its darn createElement will be the best route to go. Guess it's time to re-read the docs.....

Comment: The only reason this works is you basically missed the jQuery "createElement" equivalent, wrapping it in bling as shown in my answer.  Dang. Here I am advocating you continue using jQuery. Where are my values?

Comment: @mjohnsonengr It was a tough call between you guys. You answered my question but Kiro solved a bigger issue. Honestly, if I could check both of you I would have!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to wrap the a tag with bling:

```
let target = $(`<a href="#"></a>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `createDiv` function is working as expected and your `link` function isn't is because you haven't wrapped your representation of an html element (the one you pass to `addStyles`) in a jQuery wrapper like you do in your `createDiv` function. See my below code for what I've changed to get it to work:

```
function link(href,text,css){
    let target = `<a href="${href}">${text}</a>`;
    if(css == null ){
        return target;
    }

    return addStyles($(target)[0],css);
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaMNKg?editors=0011)

I'm a little lost actually why we need to add `[0]` to `$(target)` but we do. Maybe someone else could chime in about why that is the case with `<a href="${href}">${text}</a>` and not with `<div></div>`

**Edit:** disregard above about the `[0]` and see comments on this answer.

Comment: It's simpler; see my answer.  You don't need the [0] on $(target).

Comment: Oh, that works too. Maybe I don't need to either. But codepen was giving me this error if I didn't: `Log Skipped: Sorry, this log was too large for our console. You might need to use the browser console instead.`

Comment: That's because before, it was just outputting a string in the console.log; Now it's trying to output an object. Codepen's embedded console doesn't support that. I recommend using the browsers console at all times anyway, it's way better (even IE's)

Comment: For people arriving at these comments from Googling the CodePen error message: in Firefox, make sure to look in the Web Console (Ctrl+Shift+K), not the Browser Console (Ctrl+Shift+J).